# Stiching Aerial images with OpenCV with a warper that projects images to the ground

Tags: opencv

Have anyone done something like that?

My problems with the OpenCV sticher is that it warps the images for panoramas, meaning the images get stretched a lot as one moves away from the first image.

From what I can tell OpenCV also builds ontop of the assumption of the camera is in the same position. I am seeking a little guidence on this, if its just the warper I need to change or I also need to relax this asusmption about the camera position being fixed before that.

I noticed that opencv uses a bundle adjuster also, is it using the same assumption that the camera is fixed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Aerial image mosaicing**

The image warping routines that are used in remote sensing and digital geography (for example to produce geotiff files or more generally [orthoimages](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orthophoto)) rely on both:

1. estimating the relative image motion (often improved with some aircraft motion sensors such as inertial measurement units),
2. the availability of a Digital Elevation Model  of the observed scene.

This allows to estimate the exact projection on the ground of each measured pixel.
Furthermore, this is well beyond what OpenCV will provide with its built-in stitcher.

**OpenCV's Stitcher**

OpenCV's `Stitcher` class is indeed dedicated to the assembly of images taken from the same point.
This would not be so bad, except that the functions try to estimate just a rotation (to be more robust) instead of plain homographies (this is where the fixed camera assumption will bite you).

It adds however more functionality that are useful in the context of panoramao creation, especially the image seam cut detection part and the image blending in overlapping areas.

**What you can do**

With aerial sensors, it is usually sound to assume (except when creating orthoimages) that the camera - scene distance is big enough so that you can approach the inter-frame transform by homographies (expecially if your application does not require very accurate panoramas).

You can try to customize OpenCV's stitcher to replace the transform estimate and the warper to work with homographies instead of rotations.
I can't guess if it will be difficult or not, because for the most part it will consist in using the intermediate transform results and bypassing the final rotation estimation part. You may have to modify the bundle adjuster too however.

Comment: Thank you. It summurize exactly our problems. We have Imu data but when projecting to the ground its not presize enough, borders do not align which leads us to the need of georeferencing all images and using gdal translate,warp thing. We started looking into a bundle adjuster for refining the imudata so we dont need to geo reference every image.

Comment: The bundle adjuster updates the camera intrinsic and extrinsic parameters. Thus, it could work in your case. However, the reprojection error estimation needs probably to be modified to use your warping function.

Comment: we are running a parrallel track where we use a ceres bundle adjuster for updating the extrinsic parameters we have from IMU based on observations from feature matching and some ground control points. Then we can warp each images based on this. (We have intrinsic parameters from camera calibration). Then we can use gdal retile to actually create our map data when we know the exact extrinsic parameters in relation to the feature matched observations.  We are new to much of this, so if you interested in consulting/validating our pipeline you are much welcome to write me pks@s-innovations.net